# Start a line with - without converting to list

Tags: block-editor

When editing a text I cannot start the line with "-" because it is converted to list automatically. Sometimes, yes, this is what I need. But, when I want to keep the text as paragraph how can I use the editor to have the line starting with "-"?

Comment: What is this in reference to?

Comment: @TonyDjukic Probably block editor (formerly Gutenberg) as per tag

Comment: @kero I missed that entirely.  :face palm:
GhitaB if you're in the paragraph and you start a line with the hyphen, when it switches to a bullet list, just go back to the top and convert the block back to a paragraph.  I'll attach an answer with images.

Comment: GhitaB, do you still have this issues with Gutenberg plugin installed and activated? I just tested on one of our staging sites, starting with "- " does indeed turn it into list block, but then pressing backspace once reverts it back to paragraph with a leading "- ".

Comment: Yes, @kero, this is the answer. :) Pressing backspace solved the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start typing out the way you described and it'll covert to a list.
[image: Type out your list...]

Click on the "Change Block Type" button.
[image: Click the change block type button.]

Select Paragraph.
[image: Select paragraph.]

You're all done.
[image: And you're done.]

Comment: The problem is „-” is automatically deleted when I change the block type.

Comment: You would just add them back in after.  The key here is to input all your lines, it'll convert to a bullet list, convert back to paragraph, then go and one by one re-add the hyphens.  If all else fails, do it in the 'code editor' rather than the visual.